# Циклическая атака на RSA. Найти d

Tags: математика, шифрование, криптография, rsa

Здравствуйте. 
Есть такие данные из атаки на RSA.

```
Yc = 150817
N = 270247
E = 41
```

Я произвел атаку на шифр и получил такое

```
X = 133224
k = 7644 //длина цикла атаки
```

Не знаю, как найти `d` через длину цикла.
Знаю, что есть такие формулы

```
e*d mod phi(N)=1 
e ** k mod phi(N) = 1   //** - степень
```

Как выразить из них `d`?

Comment: А что именно в вашей методичке обозначено как `Yc`, мы должны установить при помощи телепатии?

Comment: Это шифртекст, очевидно

Comment: Такс, я вроде как попробовал через d = e^(k-1) mod fi(N). Вроде так?

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что это _очевидно_. Мне кажется, имеет смысл растолковать смысл **всех** обозначений прямо в вопросе, т. к. комментарии читают далеко не все. Ну и если вы расскажете о том, что такое «циклическая атака» (или хотя бы приведёте ссылку), это тоже поможет отвечающим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос.
Сначала я факторизировал N. У меня получились такие значения:

```
p = 53
q = 5099
phi(N) = (53-1)(5099-1) = 265096
```

Таки вывел формулу нахождения d.

```
e*d mod phi(N)=1 
e**k mod phi(N) = 1
=>
e*d = e**k (mod phi(N))
=> 
d = e**(k-1) (mod phi(N)) = 239233
```

Проверить результат легко

```
e*d mod phi(N) = 1
41*239233 mod 265096 = 1
```

Comment: как факторизовали?

Comment: Отдельно, онлайн. Главным заданием было найти d. Тем более число 270247 не очень большое. Можно, конечно, написать функцию, но это не было главной задачей